# Cascading dropdowns in google forms

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

Is it possible to have cascading dependent dropdowns (like Country and City select options) in **Google Forms?**

I searched and found some ways to do it using google spreadsheets, but I could not find a way to do so using **google forms**

Is it at all possible?

Comment: I guess the answer is no at this stage to cascading drop downs. You can redirect to sections based on answers unfortunately that creates extra columns in sheets. A separate column for each question in the separate section.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know a way to do it with just google forms, but it is possible with Google HTML Service forms. Here is a simple example. Very basic. You can do much more, but I think is does what you are after.

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rQ-yfZJEk7Y4OnxqyXFCHrxaFPLhjIPmYoQw5SJV5OA/edit?usp=sharing
```

Comment: Thanks. But I don't want to use google apps script for it.

Answer (score 2):

Use the "Go To" functionality. Based on the response to the first drop down, route the user to the appropriate section with a drop down with the desired values.

Comment: Actually, it does. The functionality of the "goto" feature effectively creates multiple paths where controls with appropriately limited values can be housed. The questioner specified not wanting to use code -- this is a codeless solution that meets the original requirements.

Comment: Fair enough I have removed the review. The comment on the other post is not visible from the review as it was only your answer that was visibly available (have some rep for my mistake)

Comment: What if it's a state-city dropdown relationship and depending on which state i select, then i need to select a city mandatory, filtered by state? I can of course make N sections for N states, but if i put mandatory city field in each section, will it let me skip sections? 
For e.g I select Florida as a state and that leads me to the section of Florida cities ...., but there is a section for California cities. It wont trigger an error?